# Custom FxCop rules violation is present in Analysislog.xml but not reflected in the Sonarqube web (v5.6.6)

Tags: c#, msbuild, fxcop, sonarqube5.6

I am currently upgraded to **Sonarqube v5.6.5,Sonar C#(v5.0) plugin, sonar scanner for MSBuild v2.2** & Previously used **Sonarqube v4.6.5,Sonar C#(v2.1) plugin, sonar runner v2.4**. My custom Fxcop rule is creating an Violation  in Fxcop report like below **Example** which is accepted in sonarqube v4.5.6 & violations are listed in the web. In sonarqube v5.6.5 the violation is arise in the Fxcop report but its not reflecting in the dashboard. Please suggest me In which place i should do correction to avoid this kind of issues.

**Example**

```
<Namespaces>
  <Namespace Name="Project Name">
   <Messages>
    <Message TypeName="ruleName" Category="rule category" CheckId="rule id" Status="Active" Created="2017-02-27 07:15:43Z" FixCategory="NonBreaking">
     <Issue Certainty="75" Level="Error">Within "violation method fullname" msg "violationProperty". FilePath="path\sln Foldername\projectFoldername\Program.cs" Line="46"</Issue>
    </Message>
   </Messages>
  </Namespace>
 </Namespaces>
```

**Note:**
Am rising the violation using the method

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(string namespaceName, TypeNodeCollection types){}
```

Instead using regular method (which is given below) bcoz i need the above method to do some check @ class level.

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
```